# Unique post author from Esqueleto

Tags: sql, haskell, yesod, esqueleto

I have an Esqueleto query that selects all of the `StatusUpdate`s and their respective `User`s. I'd like to limit it to only one `StatusUpdate` per `User`, and only `StatusUpdate`s from the current day.

I have a working SQL query, I'm just struggling with turning it into valid Esqueleto.

```
SELECT "email", "subject"
FROM "status_update"
LEFT JOIN "user"
ON ("status_update"."user" = "user"."id")
WHERE "status_update"."id"
IN (SELECT MAX("status_update"."id") FROM "status_update" GROUP BY "status_update"."user")
```

What I have so far:

```
  statusUpdates <- runDB
    $ E.select
    $ E.from $ \(status_update `E.LeftOuterJoin` user) -> do

      E.on (status_update ^. StatusUpdateUser E.==. user ^. UserId)

      E.where_ ((status_update ^. StatusUpdateId) `E.in_`
        (E.subList_select $ E.from $ \(status_update) -> do
          E.groupBy (status_update ^. StatusUpdateUser)
          return (status_update ^. StatusUpdateId)))

      return
        ( status_update ^. StatusUpdateId
        , status_update ^. StatusUpdateSubject
        , status_update ^. StatusUpdateMessage
        , user ^. UserEmail
        )
```

…Which produces the following output:

```
SELECT "status_update"."id", "status_update"."subject", "status_update"."message", "user"."email"
FROM "status_update"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "user"
ON "status_update"."user" = "user"."id"
WHERE "status_update"."id"
IN (SELECT "status_update2"."id" FROM "status_update" AS "status_update2" GROUP BY "status_update2"."user"); []
```

It seems the only thing that's missing is the `MAX` function in my second select. I've been trying to squeeze `E.max_` into different parts of the query but I can't seem to make anything work.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `subList_select` and trying to call `max_`, you could just use `sub_select` and have the subquery sort by date and limit 1.

This is the solution that I found, which seems to do the trick:

```
    result <- select $ from $ \(user, status_update) -> do
        let subquery = from $ \status_update2 -> do
            where_ (status_update2 ^. StatusUpdateUser ==. user ^. UserId)
            where_ (date (status_update2 ^. StatusUpdatePosted) ==. date now)
            orderBy [desc (status_update2 ^. StatusUpdatePosted)]
            limit 1
            return (status_update2 ^. StatusUpdateId)

        where_ (status_update ^. StatusUpdateId ==. sub_select subquery)
        where_ (user ^. UserId ==. status_update ^. StatusUpdateUser)
        return
            ( status_update ^. StatusUpdateId
            , status_update ^. StatusUpdateSubject
            , status_update ^. StatusUpdateMessage
            , user ^. UserEmail
            )
```

The resulting SQL is:

```sql
SELECT "status_update"."id", "status_update"."subject", "status_update"."message", "user"."email"
FROM "user", "status_update"
WHERE ("status_update"."id" = (SELECT "status_update2"."id"
    FROM "status_update" AS "status_update2"
    WHERE ("status_update2"."user" = "user"."id")
    AND (date("status_update2"."posted") = date(date(?)))
    ORDER BY "status_update2"."posted" DESC
    LIMIT 1))
AND ("user"."id" = "status_update"."user")
```

To satisfy the "only `StatusUpdates` from the current day" condition I have defined `date` and `now` by importing `Database.Esqueleto.Internal.Sql` and:

```
date :: SqlExpr (Value UTCTime) -> SqlExpr (Value Int)
date d = unsafeSqlFunction "date" d

now :: SqlExpr (Value UTCTime)
now = unsafeSqlFunction "date" (val "now" :: SqlExpr (Value String))
```

However, what exactly "from the current day" means to you could be something different (past 24 hours, in a certain timezone, etc.).

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks so much!